# toggleClass function not working in this function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have this problem, as the title says I don't understand why toggleClass () doesn't work, instead if I use removeClass () or addClass () everything works fine.

```js
$('div').on('click', '.fa-exclamation-circle', function(){
      var target = $(this).parent().find('p');
      target.toggleClass("hidden");
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex justify-center items-center w-full mb-10 relative">
            <i class="fas fa-unlock w-1/12"></i>
            <input class="transparence-input w-3/4 radius p-1 px-10 relative" type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-trigger="focus keyup" data-parsley-required-message="Campo obbligatorio">
            <div class="error-field-icon flex hidden">
              <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle text-red-800"></i>
              <p class="div-error px-1 absolute text-white lg:text-sm radius h-auto hidden"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `div` as the primary selector for the delegated event handler and there are multiple nested `div` elements in the DOM. Therefore the `click` handler runs once for every parent div to the clicked `.fa-exclamation-circle` element. As there are two in the example shown the first call to `toggleClass()` removes the class, the second adds it again.

To fix the problem make the primary selector more specific so that only one parent div is selected:

```js
$('div.items-center').on('click', '.fa-exclamation-circle', function() {
  var target = $(this).parent().find('p');
  target.toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flex justify-center items-center w-full mb-10 relative">
  <i class="fas fa-unlock w-1/12"></i>
  <input class="transparence-input w-3/4 radius p-1 px-10 relative" type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-trigger="focus keyup" data-parsley-required-message="Campo obbligatorio">
  <div class="error-field-icon flex">
    <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle text-red-800">Click me</i>
    <p class="div-error px-1 absolute text-white lg:text-sm radius h-auto hidden">Foo bar!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A downvote for an answer with an explanation and working example... why?

Comment: it's becoming very common on SO, also without a comment to explain

Comment: why not just `$('.fa-exclamation-circle').on('click'`

Comment: @xdeepakv I used a delegated event handler because that's what the OP is using. I would presume because the content is dynamic.

Comment: A usage of stopPropagation could also work, however that could potentially introduce side effects.